# How to get a message from GCM and show in activity?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm doing a chat activity that send messages to my server and my server send to GCM. GCM sends back and my GcmBroadcastReceiver capture it. When i capture the message, I'm displaying a notification in android.

If I'm talking to someone and receive a message, I just want to display the new message in that Activity but i don't know how to do it. I'm trying to do something like WhatsApp for my company and we don't want to use paid services.

I've tried to create an Activity inside my GCMIntentService but didn't work:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,
            ChatActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Any idea how can I get the current activity and display a new line with new message? Can I get the current activity to put a new String in my List?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bit more complicated than simply starting an Activity.

Assuming the user is currently viewing the Activity which has a list of the chat messages. When the push notification arrives, you must somehow notify that Activity that there's a new chat message and add it to the list of existing chat messages. This is a normal issue in Android where you need to have one part of the code communicate with another part of the code that don't or shouldn't necessarily have references to each other.

There are several ways to go about this. One of the simplest solutions in terms of amount of code you actually have to write is probably to implement your own `LocalBroadcast`. The way this works is that you register your chat Activity as a listener to a certain event, for example, a "new_chat_message_received". When your GcmBroadcastReceiver gets notified of a new chat message, it will then simply re-broadcast it locally and as a result, your Activity will be notified of that event. Once that happens, all your Activity has to do is add this new chat message to the already existing list of chat messages it has.

If you're looking for details on how to implement this, you can check out this tutorial which has a special section on LocalBroadcasts (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver_localbroadcastmanager) or you can also check this answer on StackOverflow which also does a good job of explaining how to code a LocalBroadcast ([how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager))

Comment: Thanks. I've reading some posts here and i'm starting to think about to use XMPP for real instant messaging instead try to push notifications. What do you think?

Comment: I've actually never used XMPP before so I'm not aware of its pros/cons over push notifications in this context. Maybe you can ask a new question asking this.

Comment: Do you know if it's a good practice to use GCM for purpose to send messages betweeen users like WhatsApp?

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html - There's a bunch of examples on when to use GCM. Also, there also seems to be a special on using XMPP.